# Django: link to url in template when function is in a view in another directory?

Tags: python, django, templates, url, view

I'm trying to display comments in a template like this:

```
{{ url note.note }} 
{{ url note.note_by }}
```

My problem is that my template is in another directory from where the view that "requests" the notes are. How do I link to a view in another directory (or more specifically; the note.note inside a function in a views.py in another directory)?

In the views.py in the SAME directory as the template, I am linking to the template like this:

```
def blah(request):
   return render(request, 'site/blah.html')
```

And in the views.py where I request and save the comments (note.note) look like this:

```
def messages(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    new_note_text = request.POST.get('new_note')
    new_note = Note()
    new_note.note = new_note_text  
    new_note.note_by = request.user 
    new_note.note_datetime = timezone.now()
    new_note.save()

return render(request, 'theme/messages.html', context)
```

Edit:

urls.py in the SAME directory as the template:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, patterns, url
from site import views 

urlpatterns = patterns('', 
url(r'^test$', views.blah, name='blah'),
)
```

settings.py:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'app', 
'theme', 
'site',
 )

 MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 )

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
       },
    },
 ]

  WSGI_APPLICATION = 'appen.wsgi.application'


 DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}
}

  LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

  TIME_ZONE = 'Europe'

  USE_I18N = True

  USE_L10N = True

  USE_TZ = True


  STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Please include your `urls.py` files and your `settings`. The url resolver doesn't care what app or directory things are in. It just needs a view that matches the url you are constructing.

Comment: Ok, have added urls.py and the settings !

Comment: So I still sense a confusion about what `{% url ... %}` does on your part. Its only job is to take the arguments fed to the `templatetag`,  look at the `urls.py` and spit out a relative url(as a string) for a view you've defined. What is implied by what you've attached is you want a url to a view called  'notes', but I don't see any 'notes' view in your `urls.py`

Comment: hi, that is exactly the problem. I am linking to notes in urls.py but I am linking to them in urls.py in another directory (the directory where the view with the notes is) and I cannot simply move them to the urls.py in the same directory because that would cause issues with templates in the other directory, etc... So I want to link to a view/url that is in a different directory from where the template (where i link to them) is.

Comment: Django really doesn't care what directory your urls, views or templates are in.

Answer (score 0):

Django's reverse url resolver has one job. It takes the arguments fed to it(either through the `{% url ... %}"` template tag or the `urlresolves.reverse` in your python code.

As long as your code is in a valid Django configuration(Below) at start up time the directories templates and views are in isn't relevant. This particular example assumes you've included your apps in the `settings.py` configuration and that your root `urls.py` includes entries that delegate to the `urls.py` files in the individual apps `main` and `notes`

```
- templates
     |
     - main.html
     - notes.html
- main
     |
     - views.py
     - models.py
     - urls.py
- notes
     |
     - views.py
     - models.py 
     - urls.py
- urls.py
- settings.py
```

*What do you need for this to work*

so first lets look at `main` I have to create a view function in `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def main(request):
    return render(request, 'main.html', {})
```

and a `urls.py` entry in `main/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', main, name='main'),
]
```

So this is my main view. Lets assume I want to include a `<ul>` with links to various notes from my other app. First things first I need to create a `note/<note_id>` view. I am using the `<note_id>` parameter to address my note entries.

in `notes/views.py` I create a notes function that takes an `note_id` keyword argument.

```
def notes(note_id=None):
    #... Get note from database and put in context
    return render(request, 'notes.html', {})
```

then create a `notes/urls.py` entry for the view we've created.

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'main.views',
    url(r'^(?P<note_id>[0-9]+)/?$','notes', name='notes'),
)
```

We then need to pull this all together using the root `urls.py` file

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^main/', include('main.urls')),
    url(r'^notes/', include('notes.urls')),
]
```

So lets stop. What do we have right now? We have a view called `main` that binds `context` to the `main.html` template and returns as a response some markup. We also have a `urls.py` entry that tells the web server how to reach that view. We have the exact same thing for a view called `notes` in a different app. Finally, we have a root `urls.py` that pull my app-specific `urls.py` files into the top-level.

What do we want to do? We want to include in `main.html` a `<ul>` filled with valid url references to our notes.

Since we already have everything setup this is easy we use the `{% url ... %}` template tag with the appropriate information to resolve entries from our `urls.py` files.

In our `main.html` template we simply add something like this...

```
<ul>
    <li> <a href="{% url "notes" note_id=1 %}">note 1</a></li>
    <li> <a href="{% url "notes" note_id=2 %}">note 2</a></li>
    <li> <a href="{% url "notes" note_id=3 %}">note 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

and when `main.html` is invoked the markup above will look something like...

```
<ul>
    <li> <a href="/notes/1">note 1</a></li>
    <li> <a href="/notes/2">note 2</a></li>
    <li> <a href="/notes/3">note 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

The important thing to remember here is what `url` and `urlresolver.reverse` actually do. They take a view name and some arguments and they convert them into a valid url as a string. Its a DRY approach to url management because later if you change `notes` to `notes_important` or something all of the templates will automatically fix everything for you.

Comment: Thank you for helping ! I'm afraid I still don't get just how to apply this to my project, but I'll study what youve written and try to apply it. ^^

Comment: Part of the issue here is django doesn't care about "your project". You have to make "your project" fit django or it might not be a good fit for you. Working through the primer(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/) will give you an idea of how django wants you to think about your project. It includes the use of the `{% url ... %}` template tag.