# Django: import two different views to same urls.py?

Tags: python, django, url, view

I was wondering if it is possible to link to two different views.py files (in different directories) within one urls.py, and how this might be done?

More specifically, I am looking for a way to include the views.py from 'myapp' directory in urls.py in 'details' directory together with the views.py that is in 'details'.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: gggrrrr `reposting == bad SO citizenry`  . The answer to this question is in the example I gave you over the weekend(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557725/django-link-to-url-in-template-when-function-is-in-a-view-in-another-directory). It doesn't matter where the `urls.py` lives, but you can delegate to other `urls.py` files effectively creating a namespace.

Comment: Its much better to edit your existing question than to repost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its possible , you need to import your views with different names , if they have same name you can do this :

```
from . import views
from another.directory import views as views2


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^test/', views2.index, name='index2')),
]
```

but its not a cool idea , you can define the second URL in the views.py related to the module .

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly. You can use documented way in your urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from apps.main import views as main_views
from credit import views as credit_views

extra_patterns = [
    url(r'^reports/$', credit_views.report),
    url(r'^reports/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', credit_views.report),
    url(r'^charge/$', credit_views.charge),
]

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', main_views.homepage),
    url(r'^help/', include('apps.help.urls')),
    url(r'^credit/', include(extra_patterns)),
]
```

written at: [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/)

Comment: You can mark Sepehr's answer as solved ;) Good luck with django and python. They are very powerful.